# US Visa Renewal

Tags: visas, usa

My US Visa renewal was denied 6-8 years ago. I did not have time to renew it soon after due to my studies. Upon applying, should I apply as a "NEW APPLICATION" or does it still fall under "RENEWAL" of my old visa?

Comment: Your statements "My US Visa renewal was denied..." and "I did not have time to renew it..." seem inconsistent: the first suggests you filed for renewal and the renewal was denied, the second suggests you did not actually file for a renewal. In addition, an answer will require knowing  a) what is your country of citizenship, and b) what kind of US visa did you have?

Answer (score 3):

After a refusal of a renewal and a long period after that, it can never be considered as a renewal anymore.

**It definitely is a new application.**